# Найти макс. элемент в каждом столбце

Tags: c++

Дан двумерный массив из N строк и M столбцов. Определить для
каждого столбца максимальный элемент. Среди этих элементов найти
минимальный.

N и M вводимые с клавиатуры

1. Как сделать поменять вывод столбцов и строк, т.к. сейчас выводит вместо кол-ва строк кол-во столбцов
2. При вводе N меньше, чем M программа не работает
3. 

---

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE  
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE


#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
srand(time(NULL));
int N, M;
cout << "N = "; cin >> N; // строки
cout << "M = "; cin >> M; // столбцы

int** arr = new int* [N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    arr[i] = new int[M];

for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        arr[i][j] = rand() % 100;
    }
}


int* tempmax = new int [M]; // максимальных значений столько, сколько столбцов
for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) // сначала цикл по столбцам
{
    tempmax[j] = arr[j][0]; // первоначальное значение == первому элементу
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)  // внутри - цикл по строкам      
    {
        if (arr[i][j] > tempmax[i])
        {
            tempmax[i] = arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";

    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl << "MAX VALUES PER COLUMNS: ";
int min = 99999;
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    cout << endl << tempmax[j];

    if (tempmax[j] < min) {
        min = tempmax[j];
    }


}
cout << endl << endl << "MIN: " << min;


return 0;
}
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В индексах запутались

```
tempmax[j] = arr[0][j];

 if (arr[i][j] > tempmax[j])
    {
        tempmax[j] = arr[i][j];
    }


for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
        cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо, но у меня ещё первая проблемка есть, поможете?)

Comment: А в каком месте кода это `сейчас выводит вместо кол-ва строк кол-во столбцов`? Не во втором цикле, который я сейчас исправил?

Comment: теперь всё работает! Thank you too much